# The uniform subspace of X is identical with the uniform subspace

Tags: uniform-spaces

If $ B\subseteq A\subseteq X $, then the uniform subspace $ B $ of $ X $ is identical with the uniform subspace $ B $ of the uniform subspace $ A $ of $ X $ ?

Comment: This is trivial, write out the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate from $$U \cap (B \times B)= \left(U \cap (A \times A)\right) \cap (B \times B)$$ when $U$ is an entourage of $X$.